# Linking custom auth provider with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, linkedin-api, firebase-authentication, custom-authentication

I read that with Firebase I can allow users to sign in to my app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Is possible linking custom auth provider such as Linkedin? I read that I need to pass the AuthCredential object to the signed-in user's linkWithCredential method but I don't find a custom AuthCredential.

Answer (score 12):

One way to link an unsupported provider custom token to an existing account is to get the Firebase account's user id and the unsupported provider user id and save a hash map that takes in the unsupported provider id and returns the firebase uid which you want to link to. When the user signs in to unsupported provider with custom token, you get the corresponding firebase uid from the map and return a custom token with that uid which on signInWithCustomToken resolves with the original firebase user.

The downside is that you don't see the unsupported provider in the list of provider data within the user. You also need to store the map.

Comment: To make it clear this answer, simply "uid" of token should be the same with current user id. For instance, user logged in as Anonymous with "V5T0SE15mublW3gTr9lr04q7uxG3" user id. Now, you can create new token with uid: "V5T0SE15mublW3gTr9lr04q7uxG3", because you know the current user id. And once you got new token, you can login again: `signInWithCustomToken( newToken )`. These two users merged.

Comment: @dino this comment alone, i kid you not, has been the only thing on the entire internet to give me the information I needed. I have a normal rest API backend, but my users first create firebase provider based account on client, and use the verified jwt payload for find/create. I was trying to figure out how to use REST auth apis to administer accounts, but i needed to exchange custom token for idtoken. Once I started signing my custom jwt with the firebase id, and signing them in, i now finally can exchange the custom token for idToken

Comment: I think the confusion came from there being no way to "link" an existing account to with customToken, so I assumed signing the user back in with my own jwt would cause account duplication, it never even crossed my mind to use the same identifier

Comment: This helped me greatly and the implementation was actually simpler than I anticipated. I would never expect that I can create a new token using an existing Firebase user id...

Answer (score 7):

I would like to expand bojeil's answer.

There is `firebaseUser.linkWithCredential(credential)` for supported Providers, but not equivalent for customProvider. Linking customProvider must be done **by backend** (or maybe sth like Firebase Functions). **Because `link` means one of these:**

- add email
- add phone number
- custom logic (add user claim)

to the `Firebase User` object.

**Flow** is like this:

1. Client gets `email`, `phone` or some unique info from customProvider (Line, LinkedIn, Huawei...) and send them to Backend including `firebaseToken`.
2. (Backend may verify those data by asking to customProvider). Then Backend adds those info to `FirebaseUser` object. (Also backend has to check if those data are already attached to some other user. You might reject linking, since there is another user already with these email, phone...)
3. Backend saves `<CustomProviderId-FirebaseUserId>` pair somewhere (e.g: `FireStore`). This is done because in future, when user wants to sign in using customProvider, backends needs to create `CustomToken` (so client can call `firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken`) using `Firebase Id` of that user. So this Mapping is solution for that problem.
4. Backend will respond with 200 HTTP response code to indicate linking is successful
5. Client calls `firebaseUser.reload()` to get newly attached data (email, phone etc...)
6. If User Claims are updated in step-2, then client also has to call `firebaseUser.getIdToken(force=true)` to get the updated user claims.

There are **challenges**:

- If customProvider only gives `email`, you need to check if that email is attached to any other user already.
- If customProvider only gives `phone`, you need to check if that phone is attached to any other user already.
- If customProvider can give both `email` and `phone`, complexity increases, as you have to check if any of those already attached to any other user.
- If customProvider does not provide `email` or `phone`, then you need unique info for that user for that custom provider (such as Huawei User Id).
- CustomProvider will not be in `firebaseUser.providerData` list, so you might add user claims. (e.g. `{kakaoTalk:true, huawei:true}`). Depending on case, you don't need that. For example, if customProvider is WhatsApp, then if `phone` exists in `firebaseUser.phoneNumber` it means WhatsApp is linked (even phone is added using another sign in provider).
- If you allow `Anonymous` users, then **linking customProvider** may not update `firebaseUser.isAnonymous` on client if email/phone is not updated, client will still see firebaseUser as anonymous. One solution is to check if linkedProviders are empty to consider user as anonymous, if that is ok with your business logic. Other solution is Anonymous user status changes when you sign in user using `signInWithCustomToken`. So after linking customProvider is successful, silently logout and sign in with customToken so user becomes not anonymous.
- If you link customProvider with `email` to anonymous user, that user's `email` field is updated. This will [force client to logout and throw](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` with errorCode `ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED`. User has to sign in again.