# How to integrate LINE login into Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I did some research and experiments on integrating LINE login with Firebase Auth using Flutter. I have some questions:

1. Looks like in Firebase Auth, there are `AuthProvider`, and in Flutter source code, I also found an `OAuthProvider`. There you can create `Credential` to include your idToken and access token. But I don't know how to specify the `providerId` in that `Credential`. I guess it is not possible, because Firebase hasn't integrate LINE login. The client side api: `logInWithCredential` can ONLY work with Firebase supported login methods, and you have to enable them in your Firebase console. Am I right?
2. So it looks like now I have to setup my own server to exchange LINE access token to Firebase custom token. In my server, I first verify access token and grab the LINE user profile, then I create a custom token, but there I have to decide a UID, which I have to use some pattern like `LINE:${LINE_UID}`. This looks like some hacking, is there a better way?
3. Admin API to create custom token only accept UID or optionally a user claim, I have no way to set its display name or some other basic info. So if I directly send the token with UID like `LINE:${LINE_UID}` to a client, then the client `logInWithToken`, it will create a user without display name if it doesn't exist. The only workaround I can image is, in the server-side, generate the `LINE:${LINE_UID}` and look up it in Admin API, if it doesn't exist, then I create a user with a proper display name. This looks again not so good, because the document said if you do `logInWithToken`, it will create one if it is not there, and we cannot use that because I want to set it's display name when it is created. Any better solution?
4. I want to link a user with multiple auth provider. I saw in the Firebase JWT, they are well included, that is cool. But those linked elements are user profile get via credential. So can we link a user to a LINE login? Which is not built-in Firebase Auth Provider? Is auth provider linking only valid for Firebase built-in provider?

Regards,
Xiang.

Comment: See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with-line-login.html, which describes the general flow, and https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/line-auth, which shows how to use Cloud Functions as the server component for this. If you get stuck implementing those for Flutter, post the [**minimal**, complete/standalone code that reproduces this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

*You're asking way too much in a single post, which makes it hard to help. I'll try to address below, but please follow the advice on [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) going forward.*

The general approach for adding LINE as an authentication provider is shown in this blog post: [Authenticate your Firebase users with LINE Login](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with-line-login.html). There is also a [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/line-auth), which shows how to use Cloud Functions as the server component for this. If you get stuck implementing those for Flutter, post the [**minimal**, complete/standalone code that reproduces this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> 1. The client side api: logInWithCredential can ONLY work with Firebase supported login methods, and you have to enable them in your Firebase console. Am I right?

Nope, you're wrong. You can also [provide your own sign-in provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) for Firebase, and use the tokens you mint there with the Firebase Authentication SDK.

> 2. This looks like some hacking, is there a better way?

The UID can be whatever you want, but you'll have to ensure it is unique. A common way to ensure **global** uniqueness is to embed some identifier for the provider in the UID. If you prefer another way to ensure global uniqueness, you're free to use that too of course.

> 3. I have no way to set its display name or some other basic info [when creating the account]

This is indeed a common problem with some providers, as you for example can't set the display name for the email+password provider until **after** the account has been created. With a custom provider you can put whatever information you want in the initial JWT already though.

> 4. can we link a user to a LINE login? Which is not built-in Firebase Auth Provider?

See [Linking custom auth provider with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171663/linking-custom-auth-provider-with-firebase)

Comment: Thanks for reply. For the 1st question, I mean, there are two client login methods: `logInWithCredential` and `logInWithCustomToken`. So if I mint a Firebase custom token, which means I MUST use `logInWithCustomToken`, right? So my question is, is the `logInWithCredential` method only works with built-in provider?

Comment: about question 4, I read that post, not a perfect workaround, because it won't be embedded to firebase user Id token. But thanks, that gives me another idea which I've never thought of :)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party .
but This [article](https://medium.com/@ashuflutterdev/flutter-implement-line-singin-in-for-mobile-apps-f64e41831aae) helps you which I publish on Medium.
I'm using A Flutter plugin  LINE's native SDKs in Flutter apps with Dart. The plugin helps you integrate LINE Login features in your app. You can redirect users to LINE or a web page where they log in with their LINE credentials. [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_line_sdk)

Also, I make a git hub [repo](https://github.com/ashut08/line_sign_in_demo) for the same.

Comment: man your post can't help because therein no firebase auth info provided, only info from documentation

Comment: yes you are right also i'm unable to find the solution line login through firebase ,that is why i am using official line SDK  for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the firebase_auth plugin? It has lots of helpfull features.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: Sure I'm using it. But LINE is not supported, and I did some experiments but had these questions which I cannot find answers by Googling.

Comment: SignInWithCustomToken: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCustomToken.html

Comment: Yes that is the method I have to use. I have to create token in server side using Admin API, and in the document it says if the UID in the custom token does not exist, it will create that user account, that is what I want. But one of the problem is, I cannot include some basic information such as display name in the custom token. So I have to create user in my server side and add some basic info from my LINE profile I got with the access token. Which means, this auto-create-account feature is not very useful.

Comment: Also, there is https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCredential.html , which you just wrap your idToken and accessToken into a credential object, and I guess Firebase will do the OAuth stuff for you so you don't need to create a server for that. And in source code of Flutter Firebase Auth, I also found a `OAuthProvider` which can create such credential, that puzzles me, maybe they can handle all OAuth? Line login support OAuth2 so if that is possible, then I don't even need to create my own server.

Comment: @XiangZhang did you ever figure out how to get the OAuthProvider's `credential` method working? Based on the documentation's comments you should be able to use it with anything, but it doesn't seem to accept either ID token or Access token from LINE.