# Is there a credential for Custom Auth System in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm signing users into my app with a custom token using their WordPress ID.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken ?? "") { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

That works ok but I need to update the rules which will keep users from writing to the database. This is counterproductive because I want to track the products they view etc...

I want to sign the user anonymously when the app opens.

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
  // ...
}
```

I need to link the anonymous user to the WordPress user. Unfortunately, according to the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking the user needs to be linked with a credential but the credentials provided are GoogleAuthProvider, FacebookAuthProvider and EmailAuthProvider and several others but no Custom Provider.

Is it possible to create a credential out of the custom token?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to link accounts from custom auth providers with those from built-in providers. See for some more on this bojeil's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171663/linking-custom-auth-provider-with-firebase and https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/custom-auth-samples/issues/10

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So, [OauthProvider.credential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/OAuthProvider#/c:objc(cs)FIROAuthProvider(cm)credentialWithProviderID:IDToken:accessToken:) will not yield something that can be linked?

Comment: That first link did it! I got the anonymous user id, which gave me the provider id. Then created the credential: let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: providerId, accessToken: customToken). I don't know why OAuthProvider worked.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, for OAuth providers it *is* possible. See nivco's example/explanation in the `custom-auth-samples` repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you see in the documentation are not (in theory) the only options.  Look at the API documentation for [link()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#linkwith:completion:):

> Associates a user account from a third-party identity provider with this user and returns additional identity provider data.

It's signature in Swift is this:

> func link(with credential: FIRAuthCredential, completion: ((AuthDataResult?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)

It takes any [FIRAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthCredential), of which there are many subclasses available.  One of those is [OAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/OAuthCredential).  If you have custom token, try creating a credential with [OAuthProvider.crediential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/OAuthProvider#credentialwithproviderid:idtoken:accesstoken:) and link that to the account.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) and [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) comments, I was able to link the anonymous user account using a credential.

I have my original customToken

```
guard let customToken = result?.data as? String else { return }
```

Because the user signs in now anonymously when the app first opens, I now have a user.

```
guard let authUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
```

I get the provider id from the user.

```
let providerId = authUser.providerID
```

With the provider id now I can get a credential using OAuthProvider

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: providerId, accessToken: customToken)
```

Now I can link the user to the anonymous user.

```
authUser.link(with: credential) { (result, error) in
```